# BatchGetItem de Dynamodb en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, dynamodb

estoy intentando usar **BatchGetItem** y no logro entender bien como armar la consulta, tienen algún ejemplo rapido donde pueda entender? quiero pasarle la *primaryKey* por la que filta y que me devuelva los grupos de a 100 items.
No se si esta bien formulada la consulta.

Pido Perdón de antemano

[encontre esto](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/MDynamoDBBatchGetItemBatchGetItemRequest.html)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberias analizar esta documentacion

[Ejemplo: Operación de obtención por lotes mediante el API de bajo nivel del AWS SDK para .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/batch-operation-lowlevel-dotnet.html#LowLevelDotNetBatchGet)

se explica con mucho mas detalle

El primer punto es que deberias estar usando el

[AWS SDK para .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/es/sdk-for-net/)

puedes agregar este por `nuget`

Despues instancias `AmazonDynamoDBClient` para generar el `BatchGetItemRequest` que ejecutaras

Analiza en el articulo como defines

```
       var request = new BatchGetItemRequest
        {
            RequestItems = new Dictionary<string, KeysAndAttributes>()
        {
            { table1Name,
              new KeysAndAttributes
              {
                  Keys = new List<Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> >()
                  {
                      new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
                      {
                          { "Name", new AttributeValue {
                        S = "Amazon DynamoDB"
                    } }
                      },
                      new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
                      {
                          { "Name", new AttributeValue {
                        S = "Amazon S3"
                    } }
                      }
                  }
              }},
            .....
```

para indicar sobre que tablas y con los filtros que aplicar la consulta, ejecutandolo con la lineas

```
response = client.BatchGetItem(request);
```

Esto retorna un `BatchGetItemResponse` que utiliza para obtener la respuesta

Hay muchos mas ejemplos en

[Ejemplos de código de .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.DotNet.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo reviso.

Comment: estoy intentando traer varios articulos, pero recien leo que tengo que especificar toda la partitionKey, no solo el Hash, sino tambien el Sort stackoverflow.com/a/21530367/8183626 no me sirve.

Comment: Entiendo que filtras indicando la tabla y el diccionario con la key del campo y el valor, si la key es un hash completo quizas debas pasar los que quieras recuperar de esa forma. La verdad desconozco si hay alguna forma de indicar algo como el LIKE o el CONTAINS para que busque solo por una parte